# Upload release notes using gradle play publisher

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, google-play, gradle-plugin, gradle-play-publisher

I have an android app that is automatically published to the play-store using gradle play publisher.

In the GPP documentation, they have mentioned that release notes can be bundled with the app as follows.

[image]

The contents of the file "default.txt" are as follows.

```
<en-US>
1. Test note.
</en-US>
```

Once a release is made to the play-store, the release notes should appear in the play console which does not happen.

Can anyone point out what is wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Need help over here!!